# Can't migrate schema using Prisma with Supabase

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase, supabase-database

When I use the Postgres database on `Supabase` I run the following command, `npx prisma migrate dev --name init`, but I get the following error (first command in screenshot):

```
Error: db error: FATAL: bouncer config error
   0: migration_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine/core/src/state.rs:251
```

When I use `railway.app`, with a Postgres database it migrates successfully (second command in screenshot).

[image: screenshot of prisma command, first is supabase, bottom is railway.app]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I fixed this error on my end by replacing the port number of my connection string from 6543 to 5432.

**Reason:** 6543 is the pooled port number which should not be used when migrating, instead the non-pooled connection string using 5432 should be used

Hope this helps!

*Source:
Second paragraph of the section "Connection pooling with Supabase" https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma#connection-pooling-with-supabase*

Comment: Alternatively: You can use "directUrl" in the "datasource db"-settings of the schema and set the Url there.